# Stop Websphere 7 Server starting as service

Tags: websphere

Somehow none of the search engins are helping me with this search. The Websphere 7 server on my system starts up on Windows startup. How to stop the server from starting up with the Windows startup. I want to start it manually as and when I need. Please help.

Answer (score 6):

Go to `control Panel --> Administrative tools --> Services`.
Search for `IBM WebSphere Application Server 7.0` service and change its `Start up Type`.

Comment: this should be the right answer. didn't know it installes itself as a service also

Answer (score 0):

You can permanently remove WebSphere application Server as a service by using the WASService command. The syntax is `WASService.exe -remove service_name` (you'll need to find out the name of the service from the Control Panel). There's a full [command reference in the InfoCenter](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v7r0/topic/com.ibm.websphere.express.doc/info/exp/ae/rins_wasservice.html).

Comment: Once you've done that you can just use the `startServer` command to start it when you need to.